# How to get the "shares" of a wall post with FQL

Tags: facebook, stream, share, facebook-fql

I can't find them in the "stream" table, nor if with a "link_stat" query... any solutions ?

Answer (score 4):

I think there is no such table (like the "like" table) in fql,but if you want to query the share count, you can retrieve it from the graph api without fql (see here for a [share count example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=218786540044_246335188771749)). Unfortunately, there seems to be no option yet to get the user or user-ids who shared a facebook object, just the share-count. Correct me if i´m wrong..

Comment: I haven't found it if it exists... :/

Answer (score 1):

You can get them via "link_stat" table.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/

Comment: -1. Firstly, the table you mention here was already mentioned by the OP in his question. Secondly, it only provides a count of shares, not the ids of the sharers.